# Segmentation fault when importing libraries in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, segmentation-fault, python-import

I am trying to import the following libraries in python:

```
import os, sys, random, glob, argparse, math, gc
import cv2
import dlib
import imutils
from imutils import face_utils
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, exposure
import sklearn
from sklearn import svm, metrics
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bcolz import carray
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
import datetime as dt
```

All these libraries are installed in a conda environment and working when I import them in a jupyter notebook.
However, when I try to import them in the terminal or using a script, as soon as I execute:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

There is a:

```
Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
```

I wonder why it works in jupyter notebook but not in terminal

Comment: Could you include `print(matplotlib.rcParams["backend"])` after the `import matplotlib`? I am guessing it has to do with a faulty backend

Comment: Do you use jupyter notebook that came with anaconda? If yes, then it uses the same environment as conda. When you try this code in terminal, do you activate that environment?

Comment: It works when I use backend as tkagg, but from sklearn import data still breaks. Yes I activate the environment when running in terminal

Answer (score -3):

Because anaconda is a virual envirounment and it works on the jupyter-notebook but not in your OS command line. If you want to use it on the command line, it is recommended to install python, pip and then the packages that you need (all on your command line).

I personally recommend to install pycharm IDE to test your code locally. It is really easy to install and it tries to recognize your python installation. There you can easily add all the packages you need  in configuration and import them in the code.

Here is how to add packages (e.g.**numpy**) in pycharm

- Select your Project in Pycharm navigation side
- File > Settings ( Ctrl + Alt + s )
- Project
- Project Interpreter
- Plus button
- Search for Numpy
- Install Package

[image]

[image]